# Change date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in openedx studio course details

Tags: django, backbone-views, openedx

How can I change the format of the date in Openedx cms (studio), in course details?

The URL of the details page of a course:

```
 {hostUrl}:18010/settings/details/{CourseId}
```

This format is used only in the view. When the settings are saved the data is send in other format: **yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ**

```
Sample: end_date:"2017-07-09T00:00:00Z"
```

I have tryed changing the format in edx-platform/cms/static/js/views/course_info_update.js

```
  $(this.dateEntry(event)).val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date(targetModel.get('date'))));
```

And redeploying but nothing happens.

Comment: What is the end goal that you are trying to achieve? Whatever you are trying to do, it seems to me that modifying the format of the transmitted parameters is not the right way to do. But maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Im trying to modify the format of the date but only for the view (for the user). this view is rendered using datepicker and backbone. The transmitted format must still the same.

Comment: Ok I understand. You are going to want to modify both the html templates and the js functions -- both for parsing and for rendering. If you are doing this in production, don't forget to collect the assets.